The command \cline does'nt work properly
I am trying to typeset polynomial division. I cannot use polynom package since I am working over a finite field with five elements. I am trying a quick and dirty hack using the array package. The command \cline doesn't work properly. Here is a mwe:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    This is a test.
    \[
    \begin{array}{l|*{12}{c}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}    &&x^2&-&x&-&1\\
        \cline{2-13}
        x^3+x&&x^5&-&x^4&&&&&+&x&+&1\\
        &&x^5&&&+&x^3\\
        \cline{2-13} 
        &&&-&x^4&-&x^3&&&+&x&+&1\\
        &&&-&x^4& &   &-&x^2&\\
        \cline{2-13}
        &&& & &-&x^3&&&-&x\\
        \cline{2-13}
        &&& & & &   &&x^2&+\,2&x&+&1
    \end{array}
    \]
        \[
    \begin{array}{l|*{8}{c}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&&x&-2\\
        \cline{2-9}
        x^2+2x+1&&x^3&  &   &+&x\\
        &&x^3&+2&x^2&+&x\\
        \cline{2-9}       
    \end{array}
    \]


\end{document}

The lines are missing in the second example. What can be the problem?


You don't have 9 columns so you need to add more columns as in the first example below, or use a smaller span in \cline as in the second.

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    This is a test.
        \[
    \begin{array}{l|*{8}{c}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&&x&-2a&a&a&a&a&a\\
        \cline{2-9}
        x^2+2x+1&&x^3&  &   &+&x\\
        &&x^3&+2&x^2&+&x\\
        \cline{2-9}       
    \end{array}
    \]

            \[
    \begin{array}{l|*{8}{c}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&&x&-2a\\
        \cline{2-7}
        x^2+2x+1&&x^3&  &   &+&x\\
        &&x^3&+2&x^2&+&x\\
        \cline{2-7}       
    \end{array}
    \]


  \end{document}
  


Thanks! I modified the first row in the second example to \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&&x&-2&&&&&\. It works now.

@S.Venkataraman yes I just added a to make the extra slots visible for the answer.
